# Is the product of two independent random variables independent of a random variable which is not independent of one of the factors?

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be random variables.
$A$ and $B$ are not independent
$A$ and $C$ are independent.
$B$ and $C$ are independent.

Are $A$ and the product $BC$ independent?
This is, is $E[ABC]=E[A]E[BC]=E[A]E[B]E[C]$??

Comment: Hint: the case $A=B$ is consistent with your assumptions.

Comment: (+1) to @whuber, and, besides, the last statement in the question would not characterize independence, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. What would characterize independence then ?

Comment: @Albert For A to be independent of BC E(ABC)=E(A)E(BC).  The other step =E(A)E(B)E(C) would occur only becasue you assume B is independent of C.

Comment: whuber's point is that if A=B your assumption is only that A is independent of C but A and BC are A and AC and A is not independent of AC.

Comment: I think the same could be said if you take B to be a function of A such as A$^2$.